# Initialize search input in jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events

I'm trying to initialize a Datatable with a default search value that the user can either replace or refine on.  This is with server-side data.  I haven't read anything where you can do this in the Datatables documentation.

```
$('#example_filter label input[type=text]').val('Default Product')
```

The above sets the value but because there isn't a keypress involved the event handler doesn't pick it up.  Is there a method I can chain onto the above that would act like the enter key, or should I write an event handler that looks for changes in the field.  I'm pretty new to datatables and a jQuery novice.

Comment: @gilly3's answer works, but it's making two calls to the server using this method instead of one.  Is there any way in Datatables to set a default search value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So the proper way of doing this is using the oSearch parameter.

https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/DataTable.defaults.oSearch.html

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": "Initial search"}
  } );
} )
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me :)

Answer (score 14):

You can trigger an event manually with [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('#example_filter label input[type=text]')
    .val('Default Product')
    .trigger($.Event("keypress", { keyCode: 13 }));
```

Depending on your code, you may want `"keyup"` instead.

Comment: That worked with "keyup"!  I had some similar code but it isn't working for some reason.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The proper way is now:

```
var table = $( '#mytable' ).DataTable();
table.search( 'initial search value' ).draw();
```

Comment: to change it outside of the init process, just do `$('#myTable').DataTable().search('string').draw();`

Comment: Actually, this is not the same.  This applies a search AFTER the datatable is initialized.  This means the table inits with no search term, and then you're redrawing the table with a new search term.  It's better (performance wise) to use the `search` parameter in the table's init settings.

Comment: @devlincarnate 's right about the performance implications of this solutio but I found it helpful regardless

Answer (score 5):

The answers referring to `oSearch` are using legacy syntax.  [As of DataTables 1.10+](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search), the correct syntax is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "search": {"search": "Initial search"}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change default settings:

```js
var my_config = {
            oLanguage: {
                sSearch: ""
            },
            oSearch: {
                sSearch: "Default Search value"
            }
        };
$('#search').dataTable(my_config);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example_filter label input[type=search]').val(i).trigger($.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 13 }));
```